# Read timeout error after Cassandra upgraded from 2.2.19 to 3.11.13

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

I have two dc cluster, where one dc was upgraded from Cassandra 2.2.19 to 3.11.13. Currently I notice cql timeout reported after the upgrade on the Cassandra 3.x DC. The other dc which is on version 2.x does not have this issue.  Could you please let me know if Cassandra 3.11.13 version needs timeout value to be increased than the previous setting ? Below are the current timeout values configured, what must be done in order to resolve this issue?

Error:

ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 3 responses." info={'received_responses': 3, 'required_responses': 4, 'consistency': 'QUORUM'}

Timeout value in Casssandra.yaml Configuration file:

read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue here, is that Cassandra 2.2 and 3.11 use different, default versions of the CQL binary protocol. I suspect one of two things is happening:

1. The application is specifying a protocol version that is too low for 3.11, so it cannot reach them.
2. The application is not specifying a "local" data center, resulting in `QUORUM` being attempted across all nodes regardless of DC. If the application negotiated a binary protocol version that is too low for 3.11, then it cannot reach those nodes.

In looking at the messages above, I'm going to suspect it's #2. Make sure the app is specifying a local DC, and run the query at `LOCAL_QUORUM` instead of `QUORUM`. And/or force a protocol version that works with both Cassandra 2.2 and Cassandra 3.11, as shown on [this page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/native_protocol/).

It also depends on which version of the driver that you're using. My guess is that protocol v2 is being negotiated, and Cassandra 3.11 doesn't support that.

The other potential issue, is that your application is still using Thrift. In that case, remember that Cassandra 3.11 defaults Thrift to "disabled," so you'd need to enable that.

Comment: Apologize for not being clear in my earlier message. I see the below error only on the nodes in new version (3.x) but not in old (2.x)

Comment: Apologize for not being clear in my earlier message. I see the below error in cqlsh only on the nodes in new version (3.x) but not in old (2.x) when I set consistency level as quorum.

Consistency level Local_quorum or local_one is not throwing any error in new version.

Also, application reported write slowness in new version nodes, which is comparatively 10times slower than old version. Application is using DRIVER_VERSION=4.14.1 can you please let me know if this cause any issue ?